# Web MediaRecorder API cannot record audio and video simultaneously

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

I've been trying to record video and audio with the MediaRecorder API but it will only let me record my screen without audio. Do I need to have two separate streams and merge them into one? But why would it be possible to set `{ audio: true, video: true }` in the `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()` method in this case?

This is my code:

```
async function startRecording() {
  let mimeType = "video/webm;codecs=vp9";

  try {
    const mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices as any;
    const stream = await mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true,
    });

    const options = {
      mimeType: mimeType,
      bitsPerSecond: 500000,
    };

    let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

    const chunks = [];
    recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
      if (e.data.size > 0) {
        chunks.push(e.data);
      } else {
        console.log("no data to push");
      }
    };

    recorder.onstop = (e) => {
      const completeBlob = new Blob(chunks, {
        type: chunks[0].type
      });
      stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        track.stop();
        console.log(track);
      });

      setVideoData({
        recorded: true,
        localVideoURL: URL.createObjectURL(completeBlob),
        blob: completeBlob,
      });
    };

    recorder.start();

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers don't support capturing audio with display media.  Even in Chrome and Chromium variants, capture support depends on the OS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia#Browser_compatibility